# No capital letter in the beginning of a sentence? "... particles. de Broglie was able to show that ..."

Tags: capitalization

I encountered the following text (from  a textbook): "... particles. de Broglie was able to show that ... "
Is it correct to make an exception from the rule of a capital letter in the beginning of a sentence, if it begins with a name, which starts from a non-capital letter, like the French "de Broglie"?
I don't think so...

Comment: This is a matter of style; there is no single correct handling, although I would say the most common convention is to capitalize such particles. You should adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, select a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and be consistent in its application.

Comment: @choster If there is really no rule that this example could violate, then you can post your comment as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: The question is substantially a duplicate of Xuor's question, so I was not trying to provide an answer so much as advice. Capitalization and punctuation represent conventions, not grammatical rules, and those conventions are defined and broken in different ways by different authorities.